# How React keeps the component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, components, virtual-dom

This is kind of a question about the internals of react.js.
Here is how I understand the virtual dom.

```
old  (rendered from component <X/>)        new (rendered from component <X/>)
null                                       <div>
                                            <AnotherComponent/> <- state {count:0}
                                            <p>{this.state.text}</p>
                                           </div>
```

during comparison the function sees that the old snapshot is empty. we create our elements, and elements from the component `<AnotherComponent/>`.

```
old  (rendered from component <X/>)        new (rendered from component <X/>)
<div>                                      <div>
 <AnotherComponent/> <- state {count:1}     <AnotherComponent/> <- state {count:0} ?
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>                         <p>Lorem ...</p> <- state updates
</div>                                     </div>
```

let's say the `<X/>` component is updated for the second time, and `<AnotherComponent/>` has changed its state before the update of the parent.

okay, i compare the two snapshots, apply the changes. but `<AnotherComponent/>` will reset its state and I will have `{count:0}` instead of `{count:1}`.

how react.js or any other declarative js library for building ui do kind of stuff. maybe I'm getting something wrong.

i think I need to get the state of the old component and assign it to a new component.
is this the right way to do it?
thanks!

Comment: A component will create virtual DOM when it's internal state changes or when passed in props change. React compares this to the previous render cycle and update DOM accordingly. Functional components will always re render unless wrapped in React.memo. A component internal state also changes when it uses context or redux connect/useSelector and context or result of connect/useSelector changes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, React uses [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to capture state between re-renders.